# Is it possible to get an average integer value from string data from a database?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

I've written a flask application that takes a users height, eye color, and email address and saves the data to a postgresql database then emails the user what data they gave me. I would like to set it up so that the user will get an email with the average number of people with their height and eye color.

Currently I have height set to be an Integer value and eye color set to be a string value.

Testing this I've gotten this error message:

> sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) function
>   avg(character varying) does not exist LINE 1: SELECT avg(data.color_)
>   AS avg_1                 ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name
>   and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.  [SQL:
>   'SELECT avg(data.color_) AS avg_1 \nFROM data'] (Background on this
>   error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/f405)

I believe this is due to me trying to get int data from a str. Is there a way to do this? Say 4 people fill out this form and all 4 say they have "blue" eyes. Is there a way to get the program to send the 100% average to them?

My code is as follows:

```
class Data(db.Model):
    __tablename__="data"
    id=db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    email_=db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
    height_=db.Column(db.Integer)
    color_=db.Column(db.String(6))

@app.route("/success", methods=['POST'])
def success():
    if request.method=='POST':
        email=request.form["email_name"]
        height=request.form["height_name"]
        color=request.form["color_name"]
        send_email(email, height, color)
        if db.session.query(Data).filter(Data.email_==email).count() == 0:
            data=Data(email,height,color)
            db.session.add(data)
            db.session.commit()
            average_height = db.session.query(func.avg(Data.height_)).scalar()
            average_color = db.session.query(func.avg(Data.color_)).scalar()
            print(average_height)
            print(average_color)
            return render_template("success.html")
```

Comment: You can't have average of String and for that matter color of Eye. But you can show how many percent of user and Blue eyes.

Comment: @Ubercool ah yes showing the percentage would probably be better anyway. Is there a way to do this right from the table itself? Like, would I be able to count the amount of times "color_name" shows up in the table then divide that by the amount of columns, and multiply by 100? Sorry if this question seems silly, i'm relatively new to databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example you may refer:

Consider `user_data` table with two columns `name` and `eye_color`

```
SELECT eye_color, count(*) AS user_count,
       COUNT(*) * 100.0/ SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER() as percent
FROM user_data
GROUP BY eye_color;
```

This query will give you count and percentage of users having each colored eye.
Refer [this fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/6980e/1) to play around.
You need to find a way to fit this query in your Python application.